# How DISTINCT statement operates in this query?

Tags: sql

In a query,

```
SELECT modal_text,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE
WHEN ab_group = ‘control’ THEN user_id
END) AS ‘control_clicks’
FROM onboarding_modals
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

I can’t understand why, in line 2, DISTINCT is used. I thought that query will operate well without DISTINCT and it does. How this statement operates in this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could serve a purpose, but it could work without given that your data is of a certain form.

Let's go over it step by step:

1. `CASE WHEN ab_group = ‘control’ THEN user_id END)` 
   **This returns a list of user_id's from records where ab_group equals 'control'**
2. `DISTINCT` **This filters the list on duplicates** *If there are no user_id's in multiple records. Or there are, but there is no case in which both of them have ab_group 'control', this is superfluous.*
3. `COUNT` **This counts the number of items in the list passed to it** *Preceding it by distinct will have it output the number of unique items in your list.*

Hence: If on boarding_modals contains only unique user_id's or user_id's can be listed more than once but never in combination with ab_group = 'control'. DISTINCT can safely be removed while maintaining the same outcome.